# I s there an equivalent to the Netspeed Applet?

Tags: software-recommendation, indicator

I use the netspeed applet to monitor all my internet connections, in particular when using mobile broadband where it also gives a total of the transfers during the connection.

I understand that there are no current plans to allow use of such indicator applets in Natty with Unity. Are there any work-rounds for running applets or are there equivalent applications which will run under Natty.

Comment: I'd like to push that question once again. Does anyone know if there's been any progress in this direction?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using netspeed applet on Ubuntu 11.10 with Unity. The real fact is that even though using Unity I run the gnome-panel. I only have the bottom-panel with the window list and netspeed applet. So I'm using the global Unity menu-bar (the default with indicators,...) plus the old gnome-panel for bottom-panel, where I can continue using previous applets such as netspeed:

i   netspeed                        - Traffic monitor applet for GNOME
i   gnome-panel                     - launcher and docking facility for GNOME

I can't live without bottom-bar with window list.

**NOTICE**: The way to open "properties" menú on gnome-panel --to add applets, configure panel, etc--  is a little tricky (at least in my case). I have to press ALT+Left_Mouse_Btn+Right_Mouse_Btn.

**Note:** I configure gnome-panel as startup application in Unity to load it each time Unity starts.

Hope this helps!
Gerard.

Answer (score 1):

`gnome-system-monitor` is still present but like most panel applets no longer has a bit that lives in the indicator area and gives you a continual view of it's network in/out statistics.

I've yet to puzzle out if this is an affirmative design choice ("there shall be no status indicators unless you are banshee or evolution") or if the applications just haven't caught up to the new mechanism.